# How to Delete a Particular row in UItableview with Storyboard in Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, storyboard

I don't know what Happen in code. I need to help my code and i need a Reason How wrong.

I choose item list in ListViewController
for add item link to ChooseViewController. I need to delete item. but i can't delete it. It has debug.

ListViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ListViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,       UISearchBarDelegate>{

}
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *nameCompany;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSArray *imageCompany;

- (IBAction)backPage:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UISearchBar *MyPsearch;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UITableView *MyPtableView;


-(NSMutableArray  *)nameCom;
-(NSMutableArray *)nameImage;
-(int ) getArrayCount;
-(void)setcheck :(int )index;

@end
```

ListViewController.m

```
#import "ListViewController.h" 
#import "ChooseViewController.h"
//#define ALPHA @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
@interface ListViewController ()

@end

@implementation ListViewController
int checkArray[3];
@synthesize MyPsearch;
@synthesize MyPtableView;
@synthesize nameCompany =_nameCompany;
@synthesize imageCompany =_imageCompany;

NSMutableArray *coms;
NSMutableArray *Imagecoms;

NSMutableArray *totalString;
NSMutableArray *filteredString;


BOOL isFiltered;
int check;
UIButton *additem;


-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else{
        isFiltered = YES;
        filteredString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for (NSString *str in totalString) {
            NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [filteredString addObject:str];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.MyPtableView reloadData];
}


-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.MyPsearch.delegate = self;
    self.MyPtableView.delegate = self;
    self.MyPtableView.dataSource = self;

    totalString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"UOB Bank", @"US airways", @"Bank of America", nil];
    self.nameCompany = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:totalString];
    self.imageCompany = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"UOB.png", @"us-airways.png", @"bank-of-america.png", nil];

    if (check == 0) {
        coms = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        Imagecoms = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        check = 1;
    }



        //[self.createSectionList:wordarray];
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
-(void)addNewItem:(UIButton *)sender{
    //การadd Item เก็บค่าไว้
    [sender setHidden:YES];
    [coms addObject:[totalString objectAtIndex:sender.tag-100]];
    [Imagecoms  addObject:[_imageCompany objectAtIndex:sender.tag-100]];

    checkArray[sender.tag-100]= 1;


}

-(NSMutableArray *)nameCom{
    return coms;
}

-(NSMutableArray  *)nameImage{
    return Imagecoms;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (isFiltered) {
        return [filteredString count];
    }
    return [totalString count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell"];
    //if (!cell) {
      //  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //}
    if (!isFiltered) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [totalString objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 33);
        UIImage *PlacePhoto3 = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageCompany objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        cell.imageView.image = PlacePhoto3;
        //ปุ่ม บวก
        if (checkArray[indexPath.row] == 0) {
        additem = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        additem.frame = CGRectMake(275, 11, 29, 29);
        additem.tag = 100+indexPath.row;
        [additem addTarget:self action:@selector(addNewItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell addSubview:additem];
        }


    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [filteredString objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 33);
        UIImage *PlacePhoto3 = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageCompany objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
        cell.imageView.image = PlacePhoto3;

        //ปุ่มบวก
        additem =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        additem.frame = CGRectMake(275, 11, 29, 29);
        additem.tag = 100+indexPath.row;
        [additem addTarget:self action:@selector(addNewItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

       [cell addSubview:additem];


    }

    return cell;
}


-(void)setcheck :(int )index{
    checkArray[index] = 0;
}


- (IBAction)backPage:(id)sender {
    ChooseViewController *cvc = [[ChooseViewController alloc]init];
    [cvc viewDidLoad];
}
```

ChooseViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChooseViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;



@end
```

ChooseViewController.m

```
#import "ChooseViewController.h"
#import "ListViewController.h"
#import "MultiViewController.h"

@interface ChooseViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChooseViewController
NSMutableArray *Imagename;
NSMutableArray *namecoms;
int tableCount;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableCount = 0 ;




    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    Imagename = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    namecoms = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    ListViewController *list = [[ListViewController alloc]init];

    Imagename = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[list nameImage]];
    namecoms = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[list nameCom]];
    tableCount = namecoms.count;

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return tableCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellChoose"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellChoose"];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [namecoms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *Photo3 = [UIImage imageNamed:[Imagename objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.imageView.image = Photo3;

    return cell;
}




// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Request table view to reload

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source ฟังชั่น delete cell  ออก

        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:YES];


        NSLog(@"%@",[namecoms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        //[Imagename removeObject:namecoms];
        //[namecoms removeObject:Imagename];
        //ListViewController *objList = [[ListViewController alloc]init];
       // [objList setcheck:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [Imagename removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [namecoms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];


}
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"chooseMulti"])
    {
    MultiViewController *MTC = [[MultiViewController alloc]init];
    MTC = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *placename = [namecoms objectAtIndex:[path row]];
    MTC.comnumber = path.row;
    MTC.companyName = placename;
    }
}






/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}



@end
```

Run! Response......

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CTASIAAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CTASIAAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

**Thank you.for help me. :)**

---

i Did. It same error

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CTASIAAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CTASIAAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

What's Happen?....................... (T-T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code here:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView reloadData];
[Imagename removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[namecoms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

First remove the objects, and then reload the data.

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[Imagename removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[namecoms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView reloadData];
```

The you reload the data before you removed you object from your data, you code crashes.

Comment: The correct order is: First remove objects from model array, then call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. `reloadData` is not necessary.